# Invertible transform of real-valued number to probability

Tags: probability, optimization

I want to use the `optim` routine in R, which takes a list of parameters and a function which it passes these parameters to, and it will "blindly" (as far as I understand) optimize these parameters, i.e., there can be no restrictions on them. I want to pass $K$ probabilities into this optimizer. In particular I want to find an optimal distribution of transitional probabilities with Markov Models. These probabilities $p_i$ (for $i=1,...,K$) must sum to 1, and they must be $\in [0, 1]$.

I have $K-1$ free parameters instead of $K$, since one of these can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.

Is there any way to do such a transform? One way to get probabilities from real valued numbers is to use the inverse logit, $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$. But I can still end up with the sum of these probabilities exceeding 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). This simply exponentiates the values, then normalizes them to sum to one. Say you have real values $\{x_1, \dots, x_K\}$. The corresponding probabilities are:

$$p_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{x_j}}$$

Another option would be to use a constrained optimization algorithm. Here, the parameters would directly represent probabilities, and constraints passed to the solver would ensure that the probabilities are valid. You'd need to specify that the parameters are nonnegative (a bound constraint) and sum to one (a linear constraint). Explicitly constraining the values not to exceed 1 is not necessary, as the other two constraints already guarantee that this must be the case.